# SQL Server Local DB cannot insert into data in new table

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I am facing a problem with SQL Server local db, everything works with insert into command, but when I want to make a new table for some data storing from dataGridView, it makes a new table but I can't insert into table the data, it says syntax error, but I have been using this code in other parts of the program and it works fine, why it doesn't work here?

```
string T_Name = tempId;
int suma;

string check_t = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE NAME = N'" + T_Name + "' AND xtype=N'U') CREATE TABLE [dbo].[" + T_Name + "](" + "[Drink] [varchar](50) NOT NULL," + "[Price] [INT] NOT NULL," + "[Amount] [INT] NOT NULL," + "[Total] [Int] NOT NULL," + ")";

sql_cn.Open();

try
{
            SqlCommand ext = new SqlCommand(check_t,sql_cn);

            ext.ExecuteNonQuery();

            foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                suma = Convert.ToInt16(rw.Cells[1].Value) * Convert.ToInt16(rw.Cells[2].Value);
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO " + T_Name + " (Drink,Price,Amount,Total) (@Drink,@Price,@Amount,@Total)", sql_cn);
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Drink", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(rw.Cells[0].Value);
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToInt16(rw.Cells[1].Value);
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToInt16(rw.Cells[2].Value);
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Total", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = (Convert.ToInt16(rw.Cells[2].Value) * Convert.ToInt16(rw.Cells[1].Value));

                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Data Stored", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch(Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

        sql_cn.Close();
}
```

I have also tried to use different insert code like :

```
INSERT INTO "+T_Name+" VALUES('"+Convert.ToString(rw.Cells[0].Value)+"','"+Convert.ToInt16(rw.Cells[1].Value)+"','"+Convert.ToInt16(rw.Cells[2].Value)+"','"+total+"')
```

Comment: Sorry i have changed the variable names from my language to English suma is for total I have tried to use it in other versions of INSERT INTO

Comment: It brigs catch message "Incorrect syntax near @Drink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like there are two issues.

It doesn't like the table name (I didn't think they could start with numbers, but I guess they can since that part seems to work fine for you), so surround it with square brackets.

Also, you're missing the `VALUES` keyword between the column names and parameters.

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO [" + T_Name + "] (Drink,Price,Amount,Total) VALUES (@Drink,@Price,@Amount,@Total)",
    sql_cn);
```

Comment: Tanks for fixing my stupid mistake with Values I have must deleted accidentally when i was changing insert into code type... But the problem was thia brackets [ ] around the table name,  maybe you can drop me a link or explain me why they are necessary,  when you use string variable insted of plain text?